# What method/class etc. uses this .jar?

Tags: java, spring, enterprise

I have a big application as an enterprise scale, there are lots of developers working on it; it is a Java Spring app, we use Eclipse as development environment. We have lots of libs, which means jar files in the lib directory. I can't touch to these jar files so easily, because whenever I change some jars, application may get failed/unstable because of little changes of the jars' new versions. On the other hand, as this application is a big and old project, I can't know what jar is really needed and which line, what function or class uses/needs this jar exactly.

So I have a problem now: As an example naming a-lib-**1**.0.jar is old jar and a-lib-**2**.0.jar is new version; I need to use a-lib-**2**.0.jar but a-lib-**1**.0.jar is already in lib directory. How can I know that a-lib-**1**.0.jar is needed or not without testing by deleting it?

And how can I find the line/method which uses this jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) from JBoss.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a Dependency Walker.

Try this:

http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/

http://depfind.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it after Tattletale